# how to use useContext in top component(http service)?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, react-context

I want get token to header of API but state of token is in context so I get this error
src\services\httpService.js
Line 9:21:  React Hook `"use Context"` cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

please help me what should I do?

[and that picture is my http.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISx1Y.png)

I can't find anything to do that

Comment: Code should be posted directly in the question, never as an image.
Please edit your question, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the following article:
[JWT in react using context API](https://dev.to/vinibgoulart/how-to-protected-a-route-with-jwt-token-in-react-using-context-api-l38)